# Value of random variable multiplied by function of that variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a discrete random variable $\theta$, which takes on the value $\theta_L$ with probability $p$ and $\theta_H$ with $1-p$. What is the general rule regarding: $\mathbb{E}[\theta * \space  F(\theta)]$, where $F:\{\theta_L, \theta_H\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}.$ I understand that this expectation would be $p\theta_LF(\theta_L)+(1-p)\theta_HF(\theta_H)$, but what is the general *rule* at work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "general rule at work" is the definition of expectation for discrete r.v. $X$:$$E[X]=\sum_xxP(X=x)$$In your case $\theta F(\theta)$ takes atmost two values: $\theta_LF(\theta_L)$ with probability $p$ and $\theta_HF(\theta_H)$ with probability $1-p$. This is because $\theta$ is $\theta_L$ or $\theta_H$ with these probabilities.

In general, if you have a random variable $Y$ with probability mass function $f(y)$, then $E[g(Y)]=\sum_y g(y)f(y)$. This is because $Y=y$ with probability $f(y)\implies g(Y)=g(y)$ with probability $f(y)$.